# Am I violating the license if I don't report bugs?

Tags: licensing

As-salāmu‘alaikum wa raḥmatullāhi wa barakātuh.

Am I violating the license if I don't report bugs?
I found a bug but I'm lazy to report it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  licensing and legal questions do not belong in this site and arw considered. Off-topic

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you violate it by not posting a bug. But since you bothered to post on here, why not post the bug too?

Comment: Because bugs don't belong here, they should be reported to the devs

Comment: no, like on the bug posting place